# No such template error when calling handlebars helper from Mongodb collection with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a HTML template where I want to show the value that is stored in a mongo object using a handlebars helper.

HTML - I want to show answer1 as the string that is stored under "Question1" in mongo

```
<template name="preferencesView">
<div class="preferences">
    <h3>Here are your preferences</h3>

        <p> Answer to question 1 <a>{{> answer1}}</a></p><br>
        <p> Answer to question 2 <b>{{> answer2}}</b></p><br>

    </div>

</template>
```

Here is my .js helper. (Why is it not storing answer1 as a template here that can be called by {{answer1}} in my HTML doc?)

```
Template.preferencesView.helpers = ({
answer1: function () {
    return Preferences_col.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}
        );
}
});
```

Also - am I using the proper mongo call in the above helper to find the data I need? (Question1) Here is an example of what is created on my form submit event.

```
{ "Question1" : "Yes", "Question2" : "Yes", "userId" : "hqWJNWLjwfggJtbPi", "submitted" : 1389406102126, "_id" : "fWEpMXX4w9wfzLg5g" }
```

When I run meteor in terminal it doesnt encounter any errors. However in my browser console I am getting *"Exception from Deps recompute: Error: No such template 'answer1'"*

PS - This is my first post on Stackoverflow so please let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, you're calling it wrong. Calling a template is used with the `{{> templateName}}` whereas calling a helper is called with `{{helperName}}`. Also, rather than returning the result of a `find` query, return the result of a `findOne` query, as the result of a `find` query, even if the size is only 1, will be a bit buggy.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error of no such template. However I am still not getting anything to display when I call {{answer1}}. Do I need to specify I want it to find Question1?

    return Preferences_col.findOne({Question1: ""}?

Comment: I can get it returned as an object in the browser console with------  
Preferences_col.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}, {fields: {Question1: 1}} But how do I get it to display the string "Yes"

Comment: Try `var prefs = Preferences_col.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}); return (prefs || {}).Question1;`.  You need to return the value of the field you're interested in rather than the entire object.

Comment: @alanning that didn't work. I found another question where they were using this format to get the value of the field to display. But it didnt work for me either.  `Preferences_col.find({userId: Meteor.userId()},{Question1:1, userId:0});`

Comment: Try some debugging. In a new console, cd to your meteor directory and enter `meteor mongo`. Fiddle around there. Make sure there is actually a question that has a userId matching the current Meteor.userId().
Once again, the code to get question 1 would be `Preferences_col.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}).Question1`

Comment: @mjkaufer You are right, in the terminal and browser console I can submit `db.preferences_col.findOne({userId: "x9G3EpTt8brjLyupt"}).Question1` to return `Yes`. The question now is why isn't my answer1 helper displaying in the handlebars? I've tried restarting the db and looked at several other handlebars posts to no avail.

Comment: @Vitiell0 if you can post your code up in a public repo we can help debug what's going wrong.

Comment: @alanning Sorry I should have done that in the OP. Here it is: https://github.com/Vitiell0/drawbridge2

Comment: This part is incorrect: 
`Template.preferencesView.helpers = ({...})`.  It should be: 
`Template.preferencesView.helpers({...})`.  The way I debugged it was to have the 'answer1' function `return 'test';` and notice that even that wasn't working, so then looked into why.

Comment: @alanning THANK YOU! Thank you, such a simple mistake. Even after fixing that it didn't work until I inserted the code from your original comment yesterday with the prefs variable. I really appreciate the help.